# One-step Stop or One-stop Shop?

Tags: catch-phrases

"Foobar: Your one-step stop for assorted candies."

"Foobar: Your one-stop shop for assorted candies."

I am really confused about which one sounds right. I've heard the second one before, but came across the first one recently. Are both phrases correct, or is "one-step stop" just plain wrong? Can there be another refined alternative to these phrases?

Comment: “One-stop shop” is a catchy saying because it rhymes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"One-stop shop" is correct, "-step" is probably just a typo.

The imagery behind the metaphor is: a "one-stop shop" has everything you need, so you don't need to make any other *stops* on your journey.

Comment: "One-step Stop" is probably two typos (-step and Stop), or someone was speaking quickly and got tongue-tied, saying "-step" instead of "-stop" and "Stop" instead of "Shop"

Comment: It could be a mixed metaphor: a one-step solution and a one-stop shop.

Comment: I saw "stop" as "shop" in both instances of "one-step stop"!  Hooray for reading what you expect to be there instead of what actually is.